# How can I read an object AND an input box query from within a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. This works, it grabs #event_note from a form and posts it.

   ```
   $("#cms").on("submit", handleFormSubmit);

   function handleFormSubmit() {
     var newPost = {    
       event_note: $("#event_note").val(),    
     }

     $.post("/api/posts", newPost, function() {});    
   }
   ```
2. allPost is an object that carries various values, and it has been used successfully throughout the program.  This will post allPost but not the #event_note, but I'd like to post both:

   ```
   $("#cms").on("submit", handleFormSubmit);

   function handleFormSubmit() {
     var newPost = {
     end_date: allPost[listing[0]][0].end_date,
     event_note: $("#event_note").val(),
   }
   $.post("/api/posts", newPost, function() {});
   }
   ```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: All three of them looks wrong? The variable `post` isn't defined in any of them ?

Comment: you need to cancel the forms default submit event first and then try to post it

Comment: When I add event.preventDefault() to the start of handleFormSubmit(), it throws an error because it no longer recognizes the allPost object.